# Why is the property length 'undefined'? It is declared as a global

Tags: jquery

I get the following message in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`  when trying to loop through the array `storede`.

I am trying to loop through the array `storede` outside of the click function, after `push()` the values to the array `storede` in the click function.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var form =  $('#newItemForm');
  var list =  $('ul');
  var storede;

  $form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inp = $('input:text').val();
    $list.append('<li>' + inp + '</li>');
    $('input:text').val('');

  });

   $('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
     storede =  [] ;
     var thisc = $(this).html();
     var updatedd = storede.push(thisc);
     $(this).remove();
   });


    for (var i = 0; i < storede.length; i++) {
    console.log(storede[i]);
    }

});
```

Comment: _"I am trying to loop through the array storede outside of the click function"_ Your for loop is running when the page loads and the DOM is ready, before storede is populated.

Comment: It's not defined until you click on one of the `li`s in the `ul`.

Comment: And every time you click on the LI, it first assigns `storede = []`. So it will only contain the last thing you clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var form =  $('#newItemForm');
  var list =  $('ul');
  var storede = [];

  form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inp = $('input:text').val();
    list.append('<li>' + inp + '</li>');
    $('input:text').val('');

  });

   $('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){

     var thisc = $(this).html();
     var updatedd = storede.push(thisc);
     $(this).remove();
   });



   $('#showdeleted').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    for (var i = 0; i < storede.length; i++) {
    console.log(storede[i]);
    }

  });

});
```